# When trying to access index.php it redirects to index and shows 404 page

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, web-config

Im using **IIS** and I recently installed a module called **URL Rewrite 2**.

I tried changing the way *index.php* shows in the url.
I wanted to change from http://localhost/index.php to http://localhost/index
I did that and it wasn't working so I reverted everything. 
Now when I search for http://localhost/index.php it redirects me to http://localhost/index and shows a 404 page.

I don't have any web.config in the server folder. I even unnistalled **URL Rewrite 2**. Everything was working before I tried this.

Comment: All that only indicates you wrote wrong rules for IIS URL Rewrite modules. There are articles on such matters to give you ideas, https://www.saotn.org/iis-url-rewrite-hide-php-extension/ but after all you need to learn that module and really understand what it is doing. Microsoft has tons of articles in that area, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure you have reverted everything the redirect might be cached in the browser, try clearing the cache (or using another browser).